# How to pivot table to create binary data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm fairly new to sql and not sure how to pivot table that can result in a binary data from a categorical data column.

Here is my current table:

```
+---------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+
| User ID | Cell Phone Brand | Purchased Platform | Recorded Usage |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|    1001 | Apple            | Retail             |              4 |
|    1001 | Samsung          | Online             |              4 |
|    1002 | Samsung          | Retail             |              5 |
|    1003 | Google           | Online             |              3 |
|    1003 | LG               | Online             |              3 |
|    1004 | LG               | Online             |              6 |
|    1005 | Apple            | Online             |              3 |
|    1006 | Google           | Retail             |              5 |
|    1007 | Goohle           | Online             |              3 |
|    1008 | Samsung          | Retail             |              4 |
|    1009 | LG               | Retail             |              4 |
|    1009 | Apple            | Retail             |              3 |
|    1010 | Apple            | Retail             |              6 |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

I'd like to have the following result with aggregated `Recorded Usage` and binary data for devices:

```
+---------+--------------------+----------------+-------+---------+--------+----+
| User ID | Purchased Platform | Recorded Usage | Apple | Samsung | Google | LG |
+---------+--------------------+----------------+-------+---------+--------+----+
|    1001 | Retail             |              4 |     1 |       0 |      0 |  0 |
|    1001 | Online             |              4 |     0 |       1 |      0 |  0 |
|    1002 | Retail             |              5 |     0 |       1 |      0 |  0 |
|    1003 | Online             |              3 |     0 |       0 |      1 |  0 |
|    1003 | Online             |              3 |     0 |       0 |      0 |  1 |
|    1004 | Online             |              6 |     0 |       0 |      0 |  1 |
|    1005 | Online             |              3 |     1 |       0 |      0 |  0 |
|    1006 | Retail             |              5 |     0 |       0 |      1 |  0 |
|    1007 | Online             |              3 |     0 |       0 |      1 |  0 |
|    1008 | Retail             |              4 |     0 |       1 |      0 |  0 |
|    1009 | Retail             |              4 |     0 |       0 |      0 |  1 |
|    1009 | Retail             |              3 |     1 |       0 |      0 |  0 |
|    1010 | Retail             |              6 |     1 |       0 |      0 |  0 |
+---------+--------------------+----------------+-------+---------+--------+----+
```

Comment: Why does user `1003` have 2 rows for online in the expected results with `Google` and `LG` marked as `1` separately? I would expect a single row with them both as `1` in a design like this.

Comment: You're right, sorry I made up the result table, but how can I justify the ```Purchase Platform``` then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `case when` statements:

```
declare @tmp table (UserID int, CellPhoneBrand varchar(10),    PurchasedPlatform varchar(10), RecordedUsage int)

insert into @tmp
values
 (1001,'Apple'  ,'Retail', 4)
,(1001,'Samsung','Online', 4)
,(1002,'Samsung','Retail', 5)
,(1003,'Google' ,'Online', 3)
,(1003,'LG'     ,'Online', 3)
,(1004,'LG'     ,'Online', 6)
,(1005,'Apple'  ,'Online', 3)
,(1006,'Google' ,'Retail', 5)
,(1007,'Goohle' ,'Online', 3)
,(1008,'Samsung','Retail', 4)
,(1009,'LG'     ,'Retail', 4)
,(1009,'Apple'  ,'Retail', 3)
,(1010,'Apple'  ,'Retail', 6)

select UserID, PurchasedPlatform, RecordedUsage
,case when CellPhoneBrand ='Apple' then 1 else 0 end as Apple
,case when CellPhoneBrand ='Samsung' then 1 else 0 end as Samsung
,case when CellPhoneBrand ='Google' then 1 else 0 end as Google
,case when CellPhoneBrand ='LG' then 1 else 0 end as LG


from @tmp
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This get's you the result you're after in your expected results. Like I mentioned in my comment, I would more likely expect an aggregated pivot here:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1001,'Apple  ','Retail',4),
                (1001,'Samsung','Online',4),
                (1002,'Samsung','Retail',5),
                (1003,'Google ','Online',3),
                (1003,'LG     ','Online',3),
                (1004,'LG     ','Online',6),
                (1005,'Apple  ','Online',3),
                (1006,'Google ','Retail',5),
                (1007,'Goohle ','Online',3),
                (1008,'Samsung','Retail',4),
                (1009,'LG     ','Retail',4),
                (1009,'Apple  ','Retail',3),
                (1010,'Apple  ','Retail',6)) V(ID, Brand, Platform, Usage))
SELECT ID,
       Platform,
       Usage,
       CASE WHEN Brand = 'Apple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Apple,
       CASE WHEN Brand = 'Samsung' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Samsung,
       CASE WHEN Brand = 'Google' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Google,
       CASE WHEN Brand = 'LG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS LG
FROM VTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you used a word pivot in your description. here is a solution that shows how to pivot data in sqlserver using `PIVOT` statement

```
declare  @temp TABLE
(
  [UserID] varchar(50), 
  [CellPhoneBrand] varchar(50), 
  [PurchasedPlatform] varchar(50),
  [RecordedUsage] int
);

INSERT INTO @temp
(
  [UserID], 
  [CellPhoneBrand], 
  [PurchasedPlatform],
  [RecordedUsage]

)
VALUES
(1001,'Apple',        'Retail',        4),
(1001,'Samsung',      'Online',        4),
(1002,'Samsung',      'Retail',        5),
(1003,'Google',       'Online',        3),
(1003,'LG',           'Online',        3),
(1004,'LG',           'Online',        6),
(1005,'Apple',        'Online',        3),
(1006,'Google',       'Retail',        5),
(1007,'Goohle',       'Online',        3),
(1008,'Samsung',      'Retail',        4),
(1009,'LG',           'Retail',        4),
(1009,'Apple',        'Retail',        3),
(1010,'Apple',        'Retail',        6)


select *
from 
(
  select [UserID], [PurchasedPlatform], [RecordedUsage],[CellPhoneBrand]
  from @temp
) src
pivot
(
  count(CellPhoneBrand)
  for [CellPhoneBrand] in ([Apple], [Samsung],[Google],[LG])
) piv;
```